# Next.js Upload multiple images

Tags: next.js, upload, multer

I want upload multiple images and take path from resonse, but I have some problem.
Uploaded images have name example: fundamental.png and starter.png and when I upload them they are saved on server with name: fundamental.png and fundamental.png.starter.png and every next file name: fundamental.png.starter.png.<new_file_name>.png instead of: fundamental.png and starter.png. Second problem I have with response data, I want res.data to be array or object of all uploaded images path example: data: ['path1', 'path2'] instead my response have only second file path and looks like: [path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0F7j.png)
How can I repair this?

Main file:

```
async function uploadImages(ev) {
    const files = ev.target?.files;
    if (files?.length > 0) {
      const data = new FormData();
      for (const file of files) {
        data.append("file", file);
        console.log(data);
      }
      const res = await axios.post("/api/upload", data);
      console.log(res.data);
    }
  }
```

api/upload file:

```
import { createRouter } from "next-connect";
import multer from "multer";

const nextConnect = createRouter();

let filename = new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-') + "-";

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "./images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, getFileName(file)),
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

const getFileName = (file) => {
  filename += file.originalname;
  return filename;
};

nextConnect.use(upload.array("file"));

nextConnect.post((req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ data: `/images/${filename}` });
});

export default nextConnect.handler({
  onError(error, req, res) {
    res
      .status(501)
      .json({ error: `Sorry something Happened! ${error.message}` });
  },
  onNoMatch(req, res) {
    res.status(405).json({ error: `Method '${req.method}' Not Allowed` });
  },
});

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
```

I tried change getFileName function, but result was worse. And I was thinking how can I change res.data, but I have not clue how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, for everyone who will be have the same issue this is the soluton:

First problem:

You need delete

```
let filename = new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-') + "-";
```

and

```
const getFileName = (file) => {
  filename += file.originalname;
  return filename;
};
```

and change

```
filename: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, getFileName(file)),
```

to

```
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const newFilename =
      new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, "-") + "-" + file.originalname;
    cb(null, newFilename);
  },
```

Second problem:

You need add

```
let filenames = [];
```

And in

```
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const newFilename =
      new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, "-") + "-" + file.originalname;
    cb(null, newFilename);
  },
```

Add

```
filenames.push(newFilename);
```

before

```
    cb(null, newFilename);
```

And change

```
 nextConnect.post((req, res) => {
      res.status(200).json({ data: `/images/${filename}` });
    });
```

to

```
nextConnect.post((req, res) => {
    const paths = filenames.map(filename => `/images/${filename}`);
    res.status(200).json({ path: paths });
  });
```